# PHPUnit code coverage for class that extends abstract class

Tags: php, phpunit, abstract-class, code-coverage, xdebug

I have an abstract class `Exception` in custom namespace which has no abstract methods. All methods are shown as covered by its tests (mocked in a standard way). The reason to make it abstract is unimportant.

Then I have about 10 classes that extend `Exception` but don't add or override any methods, properties, constants, etc. It is obvious that all of them should be covered too, but they are shown as not fully covered. I read the docs and googled for a while but didn't find the answer.

- PHP_CodeCoverage 1.1.3
- PHPUnit 3.6.12
- PHP 5.4.4
- Xdebug 2.2.1-5.4-vc9

While annotating with `@codeCoverageIgnore` is a solution I want to find out why it happens this way rather then get 100% coverage.

UPD: sources.

------------- abstract class ----------

```
namespace Jade\Core\Base;


abstract class Exception extends \Exception {
    /**
     * Additional info for exception
     * @var array|null
     */
    protected $info;

    public function __construct($message, array $info = null, $code = 0, \Exception $previous = null) {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
        $this->info = $info;
    }

    /**
     * Get the Exception additional info
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getInfo() {
        return $this->info;
    }
}
```

------------- Tests for abstract class ----------

```
class ExceptionTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    /**
     * @covers \Jade\Core\Base\Exception
     *
     * @group  public
     */
    public function testGetInfo() {
        $info = array('info' => 'test');
        $stub = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('\Jade\Core\Base\Exception', array('message', $info));

        $this->assertEquals($info, $stub->getInfo());
    }

    /**
     * @covers \Jade\Core\Base\Exception
     *
     * @group  public
     */
    public function testConstructWithDefaultInfo() {
        $stub = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('\Jade\Core\Base\Exception', array('message'));
        $this->assertEmpty($stub->getInfo());
    }
}
```

------------- class that extends abstract class ----------

```
namespace Jade\Core\Exceptions;


class Dict extends \Jade\Core\Base\Exception {
}
```

[image: Code coverage tool output]

**Update**

Renaming `\Jade\Core\Base\Exception` to avoid possible collision with \Exception didn't help (i tried `\Jade\Core\Base\Ixception`).

Making Exception class a regular class, not abstract also didn't help.

Comment: Can you post an example of which lines are shown as not covered? Is it the class declaration or the braces?

Comment: Thanks for edit, i add sources and CodeCoverage output.

Comment: Yeah, it's my fault. I experimented with the declaration to make it works as expected and forgot to undo changes. I fixed it in question, the problem with coverage is not solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was entirely in class autoloading. To get work i had to manually include files with classes sources in bootstrap file.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Maybe some example? I came across the same issue.

Comment: I guess you are on your own now, I barely can remember what problem and solution was, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The class declaration is viewed as executable code by [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/), and you must use that class ('\Jade\Core\Exceptions\Dict' above) in order to show it as covered. Since this class is designed to be instantiated, you must create at least one object using it.

As posted your tests are not instantiating `Dict`, and therefore `Dict` is in fact not covered. You need to change your mock object creation to use `Dict` instead of `\Jade\Core\Base\Exception`.

```
$stub = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('\Jade\Core\Exceptions\Dict', ...);
```

**Note**

PHPUnit and PHP_CodeCoverage merely interpret the data supplied by Xdebug which has a few corner cases where non-executable code is treated as executable including close braces on `if` and `else` blocks, the class declaration not counted as executed even when you instantiate it, and stating that non-existent lines before and after the file contents are executed. If you can create a minimal test case to demonstrate a true problem, post it to [Xdebug's issue tracker](http://bugs.xdebug.org/my_view_page.php).

Comment: `\Jade\Core\Exceptions\Dict`  thrown internally in my `\Jade\Core\Base\Dict` class. Also i updated my question with note that making `\Jade\Core\Base\Exception` a regular (non-abstract) class didn't help. Actually, as we can see in example, `\Jade\Core\Exceptions\Dict` extend `\Jade\Core\Base\Exception` but didn't add new functionality (methods, props) so i thought it should be also covered based on tests for `\Jade\Core\Base\Exception`. BTW, when namespaces used we should give full class name, with namespace `$stub = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('\Jade\Core\Exceptions\Dict', ...);`

Comment: I will try to create less complicated example to demonstrate the problem, as you recommended.

Comment: @pinepain - The dictionary `JCBD` throws the exception `JCED`, but your test creates a mock *exception*--not a dictionary. I still don't see where your tests call code in the dictionary that will cause the exception to be thrown. Your tests even state that they cover that base exception--not the child. You probably have tests for the dictionary that cover the exception, but I want to clarify that the post above contains no code that covers the child exception.

Comment: So, the problem is that `JCED` is show as not covered. Yes, it is not covered, because it has no extra functional. I thought if it's parent `JCBE` is covered (with or w/o mocks, it doesn't matter, imho) by it's own tests completly. Maybe i miss some point here?

Comment: See my rewrite, but long story short is that you must use a class to have it be covered.

Comment: You know, it's a fun thing, but it looks like the problem is in autoloader. I tried to create a simple example that demonstrate my problem and included all required files in bootstrap file. As a result classes are not shown in CodeCoverage output at all.